# Paste Special link as a Excel Worksheet Object from existing Excel to an excising PowerPoint slide using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I would like to use a spreadsheet containing all the data and paste it to a PowerPoint presentation that I am currently working on and I will like the presentation to be sync with the spreadsheet.I have to do this to many PowerPoint slides and it is taking forever. I would like to do this task in Visual Basic.

I am currently doing this manually by using paste special from Excel to PowerPoint and choosing "Paste link" and selecting as "Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object."

[image]

I don't want to paste the entire block of cells from the spreadsheet. I want to paste one cell at the time, because the cells are not meant to look like a table in PowerPoint and are not together.

Thank you,